# How to import an account in Metamask browser on Android?

Tags: metamask, android

**Questions.**
How to import an account in Metamask browser on Android?
or
How to use Metamask in Android?

**Description:**

- I followed the link metamask.io
- I clicked Get Chrome Extension.
- The site redirected me to - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/metamask/nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn?hl=en
- I clicked Install.
- Result: the Metamask browser is installed.

**Used by:**

- Android
- Model - Mi PAD 3
- Android Version - 7.0 NRD90M
- MIUI Version - MIUI 8.3 by xiaomi.eu 7.5.25
- Browser - Metamask

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a duplicate of [your previous question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/84053/16043).

Comment: @goodvibration In this question, I will consider the `Metamask` browser, and in the question that you have indicated, I will consider the `FireFox` browser

Answer (score 1):

You can also download the metamask application from the play store.And simply add the use 12 word password to sign-in

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.metamask&hl=en